# Giving different colours to nested containers in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make a GestureDetector in Flutter which would navigate to a new page when tapped on. The design on the Detector should be something like this

[image: design]

Although when I try to nest two containers together to achieve this effect, it doesn't work. The inner BorderDecoration is used for both the containers and the opacity which I'm trying to achieve becomes black rather than transparent (using .withOpacity() function)

Pasting my Code for Reference

```
GestureDetector(
                               child: Container(
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6,
                                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border.all(),
                                    color: Colors.transparent.withOpacity(0.25),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                  ),
                                  child: Container(
                                    width:
                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
                                    height:
                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      border: Border.all(
                                        width: 7,
                                      ),
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                    ),
                                    child: Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: [
                                          Image.asset(
                                            "assets/images/gold 1.png",
                                          ),
                                        ]),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                onTap: () {
                                  
                                },
                              ),
```

My Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Remove `Border.all()` from all the containers and check the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {},
  child: Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.75),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
    ),
    child: Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            "assets/images/gold 1.png",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

This will use this as a reference

```
GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  height: 80,
                  width: 80,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey[400],
                      )
                    ],
                    color: Colors.white
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ),
```

[image]